# Get the layout parameters for a HIT in mechanical turk with boto

Tags: boto, mechanicalturk

I have already created some hits, and collected answers from assignments of those hits. For a specific hit_id, I can get the answer given by a worker. I also know how to get the Question (xml string) for that hit. However, I don't know how to get the layout parameters that I used to form the question. How can I get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get these programmatically. You have to merge your input data without the answers submitted by the worker. I have [a tutorial here](https://github.com/leeper/MTurkR/wiki/Batches#hit-layout-parameter-inputs-and-outputs) describing how to do this in MTurkR. The workflow for boto would be similar: basically save all of your inputs as a data structure, create the HITs, retrieve answers, and merge those results back with the inputs.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful :-)